# why django rest framework wants auth token for every request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I just started using django rest framework.  I tested a single view function and it worked.

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def test_api(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = {}
        data['response'] = 'Test!'
        return Response(data=data)
```

after that I tested registration view and in it worked too.

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def doctor_registration_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = DoctorRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            doctor = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'successfully registered.'
            data['email'] = doctor.user.email
            data['first_name'] = doctor.user.first_name
            data['last_name'] = doctor.user.last_name
            data['phone_number'] = doctor.user.phone_number
            data['social_id'] = doctor.user.social_id
            data['mc_code'] = doctor.mc_code
            token = Token.objects.get(user=doctor.user).key
            data['token'] = token
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)
```

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'social_id', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def save(self):
        user = User(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            first_name = self.validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=self.validated_data['last_name'],
            phone_number=self.validated_data['phone_number'],
            social_id=self.validated_data['social_id'],
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords do not match.'})

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

after this I tested token authenication for logging in with `obtain_auth_token` view

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', test_api, name='test-api'),
    path('register', registration_view, name='register'),
    path('login', obtain_auth_token, name='login'),
]
```

Now when I request for `test_api` it says

```
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

While I did not use `@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))` for view functions, I don't know why `test_api` wants auth token

`setting.py:`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User' # change the built-in user model
```

every other thing is default.

Comment: How have you configured your authentication settings…?

Comment: What is your [**`DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy) settings value?

Comment: Please post your `settings.py` file - I want to have a look at your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` before trying to answer. Make sure to redact any secret values though :-)

Comment: Yeah, so you set the default authorization settings to require authentication…

Comment: aww. so when I want auth token for a request I should add `@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))` only for that view? and not set the `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES`??

Comment: Either set the default to authenticate and only override that to require no authentication for specific views; or set no authentication as the default and override that to require authentication for specific views. Either way is fine, whatever makes more sense…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test_api is asking for authentication credentials because you have defined default permission classes in your settings.py.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
...
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
...
}
```

It automatically gets applied to all the views if nothing specified. So, either you can make the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES blank in settings.py like this:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
```

or

you can explicitly define permission_classes for all your view functions. You can do that using

```
@permission_classes(())
```